# Java Beginner Question simple Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm getting an error saying that the methods are not applicable for the type Graphics? I don't fully understand whats going on here - could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and why its wrong? Thanks,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Peach extends JPanel {
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 30);
      g.setColor(new Color(190, 82, 45));
      g.fillRect(25, 65, 100, 30);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawString("this is text", 25, 100);

   }
}
```

Comment: That exact code compiles fine for me. How are you trying to compile it, which JDK etc?

Comment: What line is showing the error? Also, please always post complete error messages, and post better formatted code (I've edited your post to correct this latter problem).

Comment: Also, you don't want to call setBackground from within the paintComponent method. This call should more properly be in this class's constructor.

Comment: It works fine on my machine...

Comment: @Ravin, To be clearer, you should add the `@Override` annotation and change the `public` modifier to `protected`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A guess: You've got another class that you've created in the same classpath called Graphics, and the compiler is confusing your class with the java.awt.Graphics class. If so, you could find out by using the fully qualified class name:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Peach extends JPanel {
   public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) { // *** note change
      super.paintComponent(g);
      this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 30);
      g.setColor(new Color(190, 82, 45));
      g.fillRect(25, 65, 100, 30);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawString("this is text", 25, 100);

   }
}
```

And if so, then rename your own Graphics class to something else, say MyGraphics.

But again, you'll want to post the actual error message (see comments above).

Comment: Hey thanks, this was exactly right, good spot!! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

So I had the exact same problem and what I had to do was copy all the code in the file that was giving me errors, delete that file, and paste my code into a new file and it started to work. That's how I got mine to work and I hope it works for you as well.